# How to use DIV or IFRAME to display a page within a page

Tags: html, iframe, dhtml

I'd like to display a welcome page upon sign in to my company website.  Currently this page has some account summary data/details.  I'd like to be able to use this same space to display billing info but I don't want the user to leave the page they're on.

How can I accomplish this?  It is imperative that I am able to put the code for this within the page that is already loaded.

Comment: Look into Ajax and [jQuery get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)/post and come back with a less broad question

Comment: Why can't you just add whatever you want to the existing page?  Something is rendering the current page with HTML.  Add the billing info as well.

Comment: I don't want this info to display by default.  If they click on it, I want it to replace the current view with the billing information.

Comment: I feel like my question was worded poorly.  It seems more like a modal is the best solution to what I am looking to do here.  I don't really want to load another page in the same space. Just different content within the same page.  In my case this can't navigate away from the page they're on or important data/variables will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

The src="blahblah" can be switched to any website or page you would like.

Although an iframe doesn't sound like something that works for what you need. It sounds like you need to add content depending on whether it is their first time visiting the page. You could use php or javascript to grab the cookies and do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.getElementById ("your_div_ID_goes_here");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Any html content. <br> Enjoy!</b>";
```

this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make ajax call to page to fetch the data and append the response to a div where you want to display.

use jquery $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to load content from other URL dynamically (AJAX).
You do not need jQuery just for this simple task

```
function loadXMLDoc(aURL){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
             var div = document.getElementById ("your_div_ID_goes_here");
             div.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; // this is the content you received,
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",aURL,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: And what belongs instead of the alert? Obviously the OP does not know what and where to put that

Comment: who is OP?
You'd better be a bit more tolerant instead of downvote. I offer an alternative to jQuery which is quote important sometimes.

Comment: besides, there are in-code comments for those who can read :)

Comment: Original Poster. And in the case of Ajax and dynamic content I would choose jQuery every time. Just the "Code for IEx" makes me shudder :) Anyway, I merged your two answers, you can delete the other one

Comment: Will know about OP, thanks. There are many reasons to avoid jQuery, will not start a holy war about it, right?

Comment: I agree, Ajax is however not one of them:)

Comment: Really? And if you need to incorporate into a mobile application some html / JS code which loads some inner elements via AJAX?  And you do not have caching for js sources and you are concerned about the user data usage? Do you make them download jQuery (even its light version) each time? Just in place of this short chunk of code which you can write on your own? And what about apps for SmartTV? And what if you build a widget (and use jQuery in it) and someone puts it on their site together with other widgets and each such widget will load its own jQuery...

Comment: Why would I not cache JS? And since I use jQuery anyway it is a nobrainer to just always use it if I have ANY ajax at all